# Simple Encryption Program in VB Console App using String functions

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops

I am just new to VB and I'm having trouble in doing this program since I got no idea how to access each letter in a word in just one input.

Say, I am ask  to enter a string and I input "help" the output should be something like "$%&(".

My only idea with this is that each letter of the entered string should be read so that the symbols to be substituted on each letter could be determined (which is I dunno how). I only know how to, if the letters will be entered one by one and the index of the array is fixed OR the letters to be encrypted are already declared such as this:

```
    Dim a() As String = {"h", "e", "l", "p"}
    Dim b As String

    Console.WriteLine("String:")
    For Each b In a
        Console.Write(b)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Encryption:")
    For Each b In a
        Select Case b
            Case "A", "a"
                Console.Write("!")
            Case "B", "b"
                Console.Write("+")
            Case "C", "c"
                Console.Write("#")
            Case "D", "d"
                Console.Write("$")
            Case "E", "e"
                Console.Write("%")
            Case "F", "f"
                Console.Write("'")
            Case "G", "g"
                Console.Write("(")
            Case "H", "h"
                Console.Write(")")
            Case "I", "i"
                Console.Write(",")
            Case "J", "j"
                Console.Write(".")
            Case "K", "k"
                Console.Write("~")
            Case "L", "l"
                Console.Write("}")
            Case "M", "m"
                Console.Write("|")
            Case "N", "n"
                Console.Write("[")
            Case "O", "o"
                Console.Write("\")
            Case "P", "p"
                Console.Write("]")
            Case "Q", "q"
                Console.Write("!")
            Case "R", "r"
                Console.Write("^")
            Case "S", "s"
                Console.Write("_")
            Case "T", "t"
                Console.Write(":")
            Case "U", "u"
                Console.Write(";")
            Case "V", "v"
                Console.Write("<")
            Case "W", "w"
                Console.Write("=")
            Case "X", "x"
                Console.Write(">")
            Case "Y", "y"
                Console.Write("?")
            Case "Z", "z"
                Console.Write("@")
        End Select
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not encryption at all, just a simple cipher

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a as String = "whatever your string is"
for i as integer = 1 to len(a)
    Dim curLetter = Mid(a, i, 1) ' this will give you the current character.
    ' do your encrypting here.
Next
```

There are better ways to encrypt things, but for your purposes for now this should suffice.

Comment: (1) `Mid` is deprecated, don’t use it. Same goes for `Len` (2) OP’s code already gets the current letter with a much better technique, via `For each b in a` — this works just as well if `a` is a string as when it’s an array; here, `b` is the current letter. No need to use an index loop over the length. (3) If you really wanted to iterate over a numeric index (but really, there’s no reason to!), don’t use `Mid`, use array index instead — `a(i)` works just fine, and gives you a `Character`, rather than a `String` (same as the `For each` loop does).

Comment: Oh, I see. It still works without the use of Mid and Len function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
Imports System.Linq

Module StartupModule
    Private _characterMaps As New Dictionary(Of Char, Char) From {
            {"A"c, "!"c}, {"B"c, "+"c}, {"C"c, "#"c},
            {"D"c, "$"c}, {"E"c, "%"c}, {"F"c, "'"c},
            {"G"c, "("c}, {"H"c, "C"c}, {"I"c, ","c},
            {"J"c, "."c}, {"K"c, "~"c}, {"L"c, "}"c},
            {"M"c, "|"c}, {"N"c, "["c}, {"O"c, "\"c},
            {"P"c, "]"c}, {"Q"c, "!"c}, {"R"c, "^"c},
            {"S"c, "_"c}, {"T"c, ":"c}, {"U"c, ";"c},
            {"V"c, "<"c}, {"W"c, "="c}, {"X"c, ">"c},
            {"Y"c, "?"c}, {"Z"c, "@"c}
        }

    Sub Main()
        Dim original As String = "Hello world!"

        Dim characters = From c As Char In original.ToUpper
                            Select GetEncodedCharacter(c)

        Console.WriteLine(New String(characters.ToArray))

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetEncodedCharacter(value As Char) As Char
        If _characterMaps.ContainsKey(value) Then
            Return _characterMaps(value)
        Else
            Return value
        End If
    End Function

End Module
```